# tkinter window closes automatically after starting .exe-file

Tags: python, tkinter, window, exe

#### NOW SOLVED

I wrote a script:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.title('Hello World')
text_label0 = Label(text="Hello World!")
text_label0.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

When I run it in the Jupyter notebook, the tkinter window appears properly and it will only close, when you click on the exit-button. Nothing problematic.

But then i converted the script into an .exe-file. It's name is test1_tkinter.exe. Beforehand it was test1_tkinter.ipynb.

Now when I double click on test1_tkinter.exe, the windows command center opens for like a few milliseconds and closes automatically. There is no tkinter window opened.

They way I converted test1_tkinter.ipynb into test1_tkinter.exe was, to type into the windows command center:

pyinstaller --onefile test1_tkinter.ipynb

and it worked without problems, because then there was the test1_tkinter.exe created.

So I don't know what's the cause of the problem. Could someone please help me?

EDIT: Thank you very much for your quick and easy answer, Orangepeels. When I do as you say, there comes:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>pyinstaller test1_tkinter.ipynb --onefile --windowed
107 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
107 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
107 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
108 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Lenovo\test1_tkinter.spec
111 INFO: UPX is not available.
122 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Lenovo', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo']
132 INFO: checking Analysis
147 INFO: Building because C:\Users\Lenovo\test1_tkinter.ipynb changed
147 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
151 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
171 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3843 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3845 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
6719 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6879 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6883 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
6958 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
6976 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Lenovo\test1_tkinter.ipynb
6979 INFO: Processing module hooks...
6980 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6983 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
6983 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6986 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6989 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
6989 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7107 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7109 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
7110 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7180 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7182 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util
7182 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util
7183 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7185 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
7186 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7188 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7189 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7270 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7447 INFO: checking Tree
7519 INFO: checking Tree
7628 INFO: checking Tree
7662 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7705 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7709 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
7720 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8038 INFO: Looking for eggs
8039 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
8040 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
8044 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Lenovo\build\test1_tkinter\warn-test1_tkinter.txt
8112 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Lenovo\build\test1_tkinter\xref-test1_tkinter.html
8129 INFO: checking PYZ
8144 INFO: Building because toc changed
8144 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Lenovo\build\test1_tkinter\PYZ-00.pyz
8880 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Lenovo\build\test1_tkinter\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8903 INFO: checking PKG
8906 INFO: Building because toc changed
8906 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
10964 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
10967 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
10967 INFO: checking EXE
10979 INFO: Building because console changed
10980 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
10982 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Lenovo\dist\test1_tkinter.exe
11135 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

But when I open the .exe-file, there comes an error message:
"Failed to execute script test1_tkinter.exe"

What can I do now?

EDIT 2:
When I open test1_tkinter.exe via the command prompt, the command prompt shows the following:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\dist>test1_tkinter.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1_tkinter.ipynb", line 22, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
[7536] Failed to execute script test1_tkinter
```

For your information: There are only 9 lines, there is no line 22 in the script.

This is only when I use "pyinstaller --onefile test1_tkinter" to create the .exe-file. When I use "pyinstaller test1_tkinter --onefile --windowed", there comes an error message ( "Failed to execute script test1_tkinter.exe", - mentioned above) via an additional small window and that window doesn't disappear automatically.

Greetings,
so_question_asker

Comment: Once you create the file in windows cmd, don't exit cmd, type "test1_tkinter.exe" to test it. That way you will see the error message that is causing the program to crash.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Novel. I tried it and you can read the result in the main post after "EDIT 2".

Comment: I updated the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386056/11688889] based on ("EDIT 2") please see below. best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, Zishe! Now it worked! Thanks for the stamina at helping me. And thanks to everybody else, who also tried to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most probably an error message but it closes too quickly to be readable.

In order to be able to read the error message follow the follow steps:

1. Create the exe file with a window (if it isn't so already).
2. Run the exe file via Windows (CMD) Command Prompt by using 'cd folder_path' to get to the folder where 'test1_tkinter.exe' is located.
3. Type in test1_tkinter.exe and enter to run the app.

The error message should display on the Command Prompt window and not close immediately so you can further research the issue.

EDIT:

Based on the error message: pyinstaller needs a .py file in order to create a functional .exe file and does not support converting from .ipynb files.

The best would be if you download the file from jupyter notebook (File > Download as > Python(.py)) and then convert it to an .exe file.

Comment: Thank you very much, Zishe. I did as you described and I posted the result into the main comment after "EDIT 2". Please read above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much, Zishe! Now it worked! Thanks for the stamina at helping me. And thanks to everybody else, who also tried to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the windowed flag will fix the issue:

pyinstaller file_name —onefile —windowed

Comment: Please read in my original post above your comment after "Edit:"

Comment: Are you using conda or pip to install pyinstaller? It is just my personal experience, but I have had issues using pyinstaller when it was installed through conda. I was able to get your code running by using pyinstaller with a .py file rather than a .ipynb one. As others have said the best thing to do it is to run the .exe directly from an open command prompt so that you can read the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Orangepeel. I used pip for installing pyinstaller. I did it twice, since I've encountered the problem, but it didn't get better. I will try the idea with the command prompt. Thank you.

Comment: Now it works.Thanks to everybody, who participated in helping me!